# Response.Redirect to SharePoint Online site is prompting for MS user login

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint-online

I have created a custom ASP.Net website that will check to see if the logged in user (Windows Authentication) has a SharePoint license using the Microsoft Graph API.  After confirming the user does indeed have a SharePoint license, I want to redirect them to our SharePoint Online site.  When I do this using Response.Redirect(), it is prompting the user to log into their Microsoft account. However, when the SharePoint Online url is entered directly into the browser, no login prompt is provided.

How do I get handle this so that the redirect from the ASP.Net website to our SharePoint Online site does not prompt for login?

Comment: You can't do that on any site, not just SharePoint Online. Even your own. What you ask is for a way to redirect without an actual login. That would *only* work if the user had *already* logged into that other site and had a valid authentication cookie or token

Comment: If you want to avoid double logins, use the same authentication mechanism in both web sites - Azure Active Directory.

Comment: Ok, but when I use a hyperlink and click it, SharePoint does not ask me to login.  How do I replicate that behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what to do with this.  I ended up using a web service to call the back end code and verify if the user has a SharePoint license.  On success of the web service call, I simply did a location.href to our SharePoint Online site.